# SQL Error: No such table

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I'm currently trying to create a database on eclipse. The user will be able to type his/her name and save it in the database. Besides that, the save data will be shown in the next page.

I've tried what you guys told me previously and found a similar error.

Below is a updated code:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Enter your name below:" 
/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/nameText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Enter your langtitude below:" 
/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/langText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Enter your longtitude below:" 
/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/longText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/saveButton"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Save" 
/>
```

solution.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/list">
</ListView>
```

DataAdapter.java

```
package com.mp.Testing;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.mp.Testing.DataAdapter;
import com.mp.Testing.DataListActivity;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataAdapter 
{
// Name of the database
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "information";

// Names of the Tables in Database
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_1 = "pictures";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_2 = "data";

// Version of the database
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Columns present in DATABASE_TABLE
public static final String PICTURES_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String PICTURES_FILE = "pictures_file";
public static final String DATA_NAME = "_name";
public static final String DATA_LANGTITUDE = "pictures_langtitude";
public static final String DATA_LONGTITUDE = "pictures_longtitude";

// Help to create & manage the SQLiteDatabase
private DataDBHelper DbHelper;

// CRUD on SQLiteDatabase
private SQLiteDatabase database;

// SQL query string for creating DATABASE_TABLE_1
static final String CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_1 =
             "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_1 + " (" + PICTURES_ROWID +
             " integer primary key autoincrement, " + PICTURES_FILE +
             " text not null);";

// SQL query string for creating DATABASE_TABLE_2
static final String CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_2 =
             "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_2 + " (" + DATA_NAME +
             " integer primary key autoincrement, " + DATA_LANGTITUDE +
             " text not null, " + DATA_LONGTITUDE + " text not null);";

// Context object associated with the SQLite database object
private final Context Ctx;

// Constructor
public DataAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.Ctx = ctx;
}

// Open database connection
public DataAdapter open() throws android.database.SQLException 
{
    DbHelper = new DataDBHelper(Ctx);
    database = DbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close database connection
public void close() 
{
    DbHelper.close();
}

// Create the database_1 & define the values that is being insert
public long createPictures(String file)
{                                            
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(PICTURES_FILE, file);

    return database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_1, null, initialValues); 
}

// Create the database_2 & define the values that is being insert
public long createData(String lan, String lon)
{                                            
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(DATA_LANGTITUDE, lan);
    initialValues.put(DATA_LONGTITUDE, lon);

    return database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_2, null, initialValues); 
}

// Delete the ID in the database_1
public boolean deletePictures(long picsId) 
{                               
    return database.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_1, PICTURES_ROWID + "=" + picsId, null) > 0;        
}

// Delete the ID in the database_2
public boolean deleteData(long dataId) 
{                               
    return database.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_2, DATA_NAME + "=" + dataId, null) > 0;        
}

// Find all the data of database_1 from the system
public Cursor fetchAllPictures() 
{                                       
    return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE_1, new String[] {PICTURES_ROWID, PICTURES_FILE}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

// Find all the data of database_2 from the system
public Cursor fetchAllData() 
{                                       
    return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE_2, new String[] {DATA_NAME, DATA_LANGTITUDE, DATA_LONGTITUDE}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

// Fetch Pictures according to ID
public Cursor fetchPictures(long picsId) throws SQLException 
{             
    Cursor dCursor =
    database.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_1, new String[] {PICTURES_ROWID,
    PICTURES_FILE}, PICTURES_ROWID + "=" +
    picsId, null, null, null, null, null);    

    // Go to the first record
    if (dCursor != null) 
    {
        dCursor.moveToFirst();                                            
    }
    return dCursor;
}

// Fetch Data according to ID
public Cursor fetchData(long dataId) throws SQLException 
{             
    Cursor dCursor =
    database.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_2, new String[] {DATA_NAME,
    DATA_LANGTITUDE, DATA_LONGTITUDE}, DATA_NAME + "=" +
    dataId, null, null, null, null, null);    

    // Go to the first record
    if (dCursor != null) 
    {
        dCursor.moveToFirst();                                            
    }
    return dCursor;
}

// Update the database_1
public boolean updatePictures(long picsId, String file) 
{                                            
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();                             
    args.put(PICTURES_FILE, file);

    return database.update(DATABASE_TABLE_1, args, PICTURES_ROWID + "=" + picsId, null) > 0;    
}

// Update the database_2
public boolean updateData(long dataId, String lan, String lon) 
{                                            
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();                             
    args.put(DATA_LANGTITUDE, lan);
    args.put(DATA_LONGTITUDE, lon);

    return database.update(DATABASE_TABLE_2, args, DATA_NAME + "=" + dataId, null) > 0;    
}
}
```

DataListActivity.java

```
package com.mp.Testing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class DataListActivity extends ListActivity 
{
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

// Define the variables
private DataAdapter DbHelper;  

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    DbHelper = new DataAdapter(this);
    DbHelper.open();
    fillData();                                                           
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

// Fill the data in the database
private void fillPictures() 
{
    Cursor dbCursor = DbHelper.fetchAllData();               
    startManagingCursor(dbCursor);                                 

    // Creating an array to specify the fields we want 
    String[] dat = new String[]{DataAdapter.PICTURES_FILE};  

    // An array of the fields we want to bind in the view
    int[] dato = new int[]{R.id.nameText};                                     

    // Create a simple cursor adapter & display it
    SimpleCursorAdapter reminders = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.solution, dbCursor, dat, dato);                           
    setListAdapter(reminders);                                            
 }

// Fill the data in the database
private void fillData() 
{
    Cursor dbCursor = DbHelper.fetchAllData();               
    startManagingCursor(dbCursor);                                 

    // Creating an array to specify the fields we want 
    String[] lan = new String[]{DataAdapter.DATA_LANGTITUDE};  
    String[] lon = new String[]{DataAdapter.DATA_LONGTITUDE}; 

    // An array of the fields we want to bind in the view
    int[] lanto = new int[]{R.id.langText};  
    int[] lonto = new int[]{R.id.longText};

    // Create a simple cursor adapter & display it
    SimpleCursorAdapter landers = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.solution, dbCursor, lan, lanto);                           
    setListAdapter(landers); 

    // Create a simple cursor adapter & display it
    SimpleCursorAdapter londers = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.solution, dbCursor, lon, lonto);                           
    setListAdapter(londers);
 }

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DataEditActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(DataAdapter.PICTURES_ROWID, id);
    i.putExtra(DataAdapter.DATA_NAME, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
 }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    fillData();                                                           
 }

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{                     
    switch(item.getItemId()) 

    {
        case R.id.list:
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();    
        DbHelper.deleteData(info.id);                            
        fillData();                                                   
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

DataEditActivity.java

```
package com.mp.Testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DataEditActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
private DataAdapter DbHelper;
private Long mPicsId;
private Long mDataId;
private EditText ET;
private EditText LAT;
private EditText LOT;
private Button SB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    DbHelper = new DataAdapter(this);

    ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    LAT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.langText);
    LOT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.longText);
    SB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

    mPicsId = savedInstanceState != null                                  
    ? savedInstanceState.getLong(DataAdapter.PICTURES_ROWID): null;
    mDataId = savedInstanceState != null                                  
    ? savedInstanceState.getLong(DataAdapter.DATA_NAME): null;
    registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText();
}

private void registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
        saveState();                                                
            setResult(RESULT_OK);                                       
            Toast.makeText(DataEditActivity.this,                   
            getString(R.string.message),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();                                                   
         }
    });
}

// Intent to start the activity
private void setRowIdFromIntent() 
{                                      
    if (mPicsId == null) 
    {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mPicsId = extras != null
        ? extras.getLong(DataAdapter.PICTURES_ROWID): null;
   }
   if (mDataId == null) 
   {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mDataId = extras != null
        ? extras.getLong(DataAdapter.DATA_NAME): null;
   }
}

// Database is close when it is pause
@Override
protected void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
    DbHelper.close();                                                    
}

// Resume the database
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{                                                
    super.onResume();
    DbHelper.open();                                                     
    setRowIdFromIntent();                                                 
    populateFields();                                                     
}

// Populate the form
private void populateFields()  
{                                          
    if (mPicsId != null) 
    {
        Cursor pics = DbHelper.fetchData(mPicsId);                
        startManagingCursor(pics);            

        ET.setText(pics.getString(
        pics.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataAdapter.PICTURES_FILE)));       
    }
    if (mDataId != null) 
    {
        Cursor data = DbHelper.fetchData(mDataId);                
        startManagingCursor(data);            

        LAT.setText(data.getString(
        data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataAdapter.DATA_LANGTITUDE)));  
        LOT.setText(data.getString(
        data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataAdapter.DATA_LONGTITUDE))); 
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putLong(DataAdapter.PICTURES_ROWID, mPicsId); 
    outState.putLong(DataAdapter.DATA_NAME, mDataId); 
}

private void saveState() 
{
    String file = ET.getText().toString();
    String lan = LAT.getText().toString();
    String lon = LOT.getText().toString();

    if (mPicsId == null && mDataId == null) 
    {                                                 
        long id = DbHelper.createPictures(file);
        long ild = DbHelper.createData(lan, lon);

        if (id > 0 && ild > 0) 
        {                                                     
            mPicsId = id;  
            mDataId = ild;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        DbHelper.updatePictures(mPicsId, file);  
        DbHelper.updateData(mDataId, lan, lon);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Intent i = new Intent(DataEditActivity.this, DataEditActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

DataDBHelper.java

```
package com.mp.Testing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
// Name & the version of Database.
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "information";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Names of the Tables in Database
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_1 = "pictures";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_2 = "data";

// Columns present in DATABASE_TABLE
public static final String PICTURES_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String PICTURES_FILE = "pictures_file";
public static final String DATA_NAME = "_name";
public static final String DATA_LANGTITUDE = "pictures_langtitude";
public static final String DATA_LONGTITUDE = "pictures_longtitude";

// SQL query string for creating DATABASE_TABLE_1
static final String CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_1 =
             "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_1 + " (" + PICTURES_ROWID +
             " integer primary key autoincrement, " + PICTURES_FILE +
             " text not null);";

// SQL query string for creating DATABASE_TABLE_2
static final String CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_2 =
             "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_2 + " (" + DATA_NAME +
             " integer primary key autoincrement, " + DATA_LANGTITUDE +
             " text not null, " + DATA_LONGTITUDE + " text not null);";

// To execute the SQL command
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) 
{
    database.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_1);
    database.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_2);
    Log.d("SaveData", "Created DB");
}

public static final String TAG_1 = "PICTURES_TABLE";
public static final String TAG_2 = "DATA_TABLE";

private Context context;

// Constructor
public DataDBHelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

// Upgrading the database version
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}

// Inserting pictures into database
private void insertDataIntoPictures(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    try
    {
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.picture);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String strLine = null;

        while ((strLine = (br.readLine()).trim()) != null) 
        {
            String[] temp = null;

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

            initialValues.put(PICTURES_FILE, temp[0].trim());

            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_1, null, initialValues);
        }
    is.close();
    }   
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG_1, "Error while inserting common names into table");
    }
}

// Inserting data into database
private void insertDataIntoData(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    try
    {
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String strLine = null;

        while ((strLine = (br.readLine()).trim()) != null) 
        {
            String[] temp = null;

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

            initialValues.put(DATA_LANGTITUDE, temp[0]);
            initialValues.put(DATA_LONGTITUDE, temp[1]);

            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_2, null, initialValues);
        }
    is.close();
    }   
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG_2, "Error while inserting common names into table");
    }
}
}
```

This is the error that I received:

01-23 18:20:39.465: E/Database(4837): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: data: , while compiling: INSERT INTO data(pictures_longtitude, pictures_langtitude) VALUES(?, ?);

Hope all can help me to resolve it and point out any error that I've written in my code. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of things there is a string of SQL called: `CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_1` and it execs in `onCreate`, but there isn't a `CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_2` string and it's not being executed on the database.
`DATABASE_TABLE_2` is set to be `"data"` so it should just be matter of putting together a `CREATE TABLE` script and using it in `onCreate` on your `DataDBHelper`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me! I did what you told me and encounter an error. Above is the updated version of code.

Comment: Are you seeing the "Created DB" in your logs? Need to determine if onCreate is even firing.

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate() method of DataDBHelper.java you are not creating the second table.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) 
{
    database.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_1);
    Log.d("SaveData", "Created DB");
}
```

You need to create the table here

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) 
{
    database.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_1);
    database.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_2);
    Log.d("SaveData", "Created DB");
}
```

CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_2 = "my sql stament for table 2";

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me! I did what you told me and encounter an error. Above is the updated version of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your onCreate has create table for only for **pictures**

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)  {     database.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_1);    
 Log.d("SaveData", "Created DB"); }
```

But as per your exception message you are trying to insert into **data**

while compiling: INSERT INTO **data**(pictures_file, pictures_count) VALUES(?, ?);

Add create table for data also if you want to do insert into data table, otherwise, some where your table name is getting passed wrong, check it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me! I did what you told me and encounter an error. Above is the updated version of code.

Answer (score -2):

Too much code to bother reading.

I'll bet you're not connecting to the database you think you are OR the table has not yet been created in the database you're successfully connecting to.  Check both.

You should be able to isolate persistence code to one class and unit test it.  If not, I'd consider redesigning to make this possible.

Comment: That's not very helpful really. If you can't be bothered to read the code, then please don't just guess an answer!

Comment: It looks like it's spot on - the other answers are pointing out that you didn't create the table.  I figured it out faster and without bothering to read your code.  Some mistakes don't take any effort to figure out.  Check your assumptions....

Comment: Chill chill! I'm thankful for you guys helping me out. :) I did what you told me and encounter an error. Above is the updated version of code.

Comment: Chill yourself.  You're the one chiding me for not reading the code.  I wasn't guessing.  I knew.